# How can I Override the woocommerce_download_file_redirect function?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was asked to help a friend with virtual product download issues with their WooCommerce site. I solved the problem in the short term by moving them off their Hostgator shared hosting to a dedicated VPS through Digital Ocean (DO). However, I need to take this one step further as storing their files on droplets is going to get expensive really fast.

What I am wanting to do is use DOs Spaces, which are effectively S3 buckets. The tests we have done suggest this will be a really good setup as the storage space is very cheap compared to droplets, and we can use a CDN feature. Unfortunately, I am having issues working out how to best integrate WooCommerce digital downloads with Spaces. WooCommerce provides three download options:

- The first two seem to proxy the file through your webserver to hide the origin URL
- The third option 'Redirect (insecure)' updates the database to show you've downloaded the product, and then redirects you to a static link.

I want to use the redirect option and override the plugin function `woocommerce_download_file_redirect` with my own code that would use DOs API to generate a pre-signed download URL for a protected resource that is valid for no more than 60 seconds, thus protecting the download from unauthorized users.

After looking through the documentation, I came across [the function](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-download-handler.html#source-view.243) which handles the redirect, and on [line 25 of the same class](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-download-handler.html#source-view.25) the line of code that registered that action. Knowing about these functions I wrote a simple plugin to test overriding that code

```
<?php
/**
  * plugin meta here (name, uri, description etc)
  */
 function download_redirect_override() {
   var_dump('test to see if my code works');
   // Once I get this to work, this method will take the product URL
   // explode it on '/' to get the parts required to make an API call to Spaces
   // to generate a pre-signed URL with a 60-second life-span
   // this URL will then be returned to the user using Header('Location: '.$url); die;
 }

 add_action( 'init', function() {
    global $WC_Download_Handler;

    // remove the default action so I can replace it with my one that generates short-life download URLs
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_download_file_redirect', array( $WC_Download_Handler, 'download_file_redirect' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_download_file_redirect', 'download_redirect_override', 10, 2 );
 });
```

Once my plugin is enabled, I try hitting the download button and WooCommerce ignores my code continuing to use the default function. I know my `add_action( 'init', ..)` is getting called because I have inserted a `var_dump('test');` in the function and that prints to my screen.

I am not a PHP developer so I don't fully understand the nuances of Word Press. I am hoping someone could either point out what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to redirect to your custom path?

Comment: Yes, I do, but the catch is this custom path would be different every time someone clicks the 'Download' button and needs to be generated on the fly. The link would only be valid for 60 or so seconds.

Edit: [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3-sdk-examples/#generate-a-pre-signed-url-to-download-a-private-file) shows the API call I want to make when generating links. The only issue is working out how to force WooCommerce to use my generated link rather than the one stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a break for a few days, I spent last night and finally got it working.

While the code below works, I may well be doing it wrong so I am still open to feedback. Here is my code:

> The function `spaces_download` is in another file, I have not posted it below as it is not relevant, however, it ends with a Header('Location: '.$Url); Exit();

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: <redacted>
 * Plugin URI: <redacted>
 * Description: <redacted>
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Author: <redacted>
 * Author URI: <redacted>
 */

add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {
    // Override the default Woo Commerce function that handles the redirect download
    // The third arg, '1', is the priority, we use this to override the default 
    add_action( 'woocommerce_download_file_redirect', 'spaces_download', 1, 1 );
}
```